# "logarithmic" linear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you please refer me to a known conceptual field I can use a terminology and established features from, while dealing with following structures:

I have a ("logarithmic") linear function space $F$ of positive-definite (homogeneous in my case) functions 
$f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\Rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Discrete set of distinct functions $\{f_k\},  f_{k}\in F$ defines a complete ("logarithmic") basis in $F$ if all $f_k$ are ("logarithmically") independent, i.e.:

$\neg\,\exists\,\, \{\alpha_k\},\, \alpha_k\in\mathbb{R}:\quad \prod_{k}f_{k}^{\alpha_k}=1$ ;

and any function in $F$ can be expressed as a product of real powers of basic functions:

$\forall f\in F \quad\,\,\exists\, \{\alpha_k\},\, \alpha_k\in\mathbb{R}:\quad f=\prod_{k}f_{k}^{\alpha_k}$ ;

(It is probably better to define $F$ here as a projective space.)

This looks pretty straightforward and in a very close analogy to standard linear spaces, - just addition is replaced by multiplication.
It may not though be directly the same as just linear space for $ln(f)$, especially in a little different case of natural powers $\{\alpha_k\}$, $\alpha_k\in\mathbb{N}$, when the requirement of positive-definiteness for our (homogeneous) functions can be eased: $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\Rightarrow\mathbb{R}\quad$ (where it may simply look like a group).

I failed to google anything reasonable for this and do not want to play a "wheel reinventor".

Comment: What you call "logarithmic independence" is usually called [multiplicative independence](http://planetmath.org/multiplicativelyindependent), although I've only seen it used in number theory. Hope this helps...